# I am on Powershell 5.1 I am looping over a directory and I need to 275 days to the CreationTime and LastWriteTime

Tags: powershell

I need to add 275 days to the Each file in the directories $object.CreationTime and $object.LastWriteTime. In the same format as this 10 November 2016 12:00:00. I will take that variable and remove the strings being passed in now.

```
$files =  Get-ChildItem -force | Where-Object {! $_.PSIsContainer} 
foreach($object in $files)
{
     $object.CreationTime=("10 November 2016 12:00:00")
     $object.LastWriteTime=("10 November 2016 12:00:00")
}
```

Comment: What's the issue with your code? Seems fine for your need, however you should note that this only works because you're passing a valid `DateTime` formatted string.

Comment: As an aside: In PSv3+ `Get-ChildItem` supports `-File` and `-Directory` switches, so you can simplify `Get-ChildItem -Force | Where-Object {! $_.PSIsContainer}` to `Get-ChildItem -File -Force`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to "add 275 days" to the timestamps, use the `AddDays` method. The question makes it appear that you want to hardcode a specific date.

```
$files =  Get-ChildItem -force | Where-Object {! $_.PSIsContainer} 
foreach($object in $files)
{
     $object.CreationTime = $object.CreationTime.AddDays(275)
     $object.LastWriteTime = $object.LastWriteTime.AddDays(275)
}
```

Using PowerShell 5.1 and higher, the `-File` switch obviates the need to check  `PSIsContainer`.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Force -File
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly this may work...

```
$newDateString = '10 November 2016 12:00:00';
```

In loop:

```
$object.CreationTime = Get-Date($newDateString);
$object.LastWriteTime = Get-Date($newDateString);
```

Comment: `$object.CreationTime = '10 November 2016 12:00:00'` should also work without any issues since the string can be type converted without the need of parsing

Comment: @santiago-squarzon Lol. Yeah, honestly have never applied a string directly to a filestamp. Seems I've by habit done a Get-Date rather than using the [DateTime] variable type to convert. Not much scripting, for me, requiring DateTime accuracy so most is Get-Date('4/1/2022') to get datetime from a partial to pass to things like SQL statements where I need just two range variables

Comment: As an aside: It's best to avoid pseudo method syntax -> `Get-Date $newDateString` (which is the same as `Get-Date -Date $newDateString`) and to avoid unnecessary use of `;` (only needed to place multiple statements _on the same line_).